# Apache virtualhost defaults to FQDN

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have set up a VirtualHost on my Apache system which happens to have the same name as the FQDN of the server. This is the FQDN:

```
root@mail:/etc/apache2/sites-available# hostname -f
mail.example.com
```

This is the contents of the .conf files:

```
000-default.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

example.com.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mail.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I would expect mail.example.com would match the VirtualHost, and as a consequence use the DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html. 
It does not.

Running apache2ctl -S yields:

```
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server mail.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost mail.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost mail.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/abcarrental.nl.conf:1)
```

So the default server is mail.example.com and consequently the DocumentRoot is /var/www/html.

Choosing a different VirtualHost name (e.g. webmail.example.com) and changing the VirtualHostName to webmail.example.com solves the problem.

I have gone through the Apache NamedVirtualHost manual pages and I cannot find an explanation. Only explanation that if a name does *not* match any of the vhosts, the default is used. But nothing that the default is used if the FQDM is equal to the requested name.

Is this behaviour by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's by design when you omit a ServerName from a VirtualHost that is is initialized from the systems local hostname, or barring that, from the reverse DNS lookup of any local IP address.

This config is unfortunately done by the default virtual host created by debian/ubuntu packages.

With hindsight -- It's considered preferrable to set a completely dummy ServerName in a catch-all (first listed) virtual host.

Comment: AH! I get it what you mean with "omitting a ServerName from a Virtualhost". The 000-default.conf file has a VirtualHost without a name. And that makes it is initialized with the hostname. And yes, entering a dummy servername would solve that. Strange that the absence of a ServerName is not corrected when it is eventually specified in the next VirtualHost.

Comment: The one in the next vhost is just for the next vhost

Comment: No it is not. That is what makes it confusing. The next vhost is simply ignored as the default takes preference over a a specified vhost. The explanation in your answer was correct and very clear.

Comment: This just drove me up the wall, as usual when editing Apache config files. Thanks so much for your clarification.